# Facebook app testers not receiving notification

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

I am writing an Android app which makes use the the Facebook SDK (specifically the login and friends list). I added the first 4 testers to https://developers.facebook.com/apps/{APP-ID}/roles/roles/ without any problems (these users were not asked to confirm that they would like to be testers they were just made testers immediately) and since then any tester I add is marked as "pending" but the user never receives a notification inviting them to become a tester (except for one instance where a user did receive a notification in their normal Facebook notifications). I believe this question has been asked before but so far there is no answer and Facebook provides no forum to discuss this problem in, evidenced by this question https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=3608173820208

Comment: Have those users registered as developers on https://developers.facebook.com/ ? (Don't ask me where/how exactly, too long ago I did that myself.) It requires the accounts to be verified by either text message or via credit card info first, IIRC.

Comment: So far it seems that even users without development accounts can become testers, but the notification which requests their permission only shows on laptops/desktops, not phones (which is how most people use Facebook :P).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well as I mentioned the first couple of developers I added were added immediately (and these were users who also did not have Facebook Developer accounts), and after that any friend I added was immediately marked as "Pending".

Since then I found that:

a) Users will only receive the notification inviting them to become a developer on a desktop or laptop (not a mobile device)

b) When a user does accept the invitation the confirm button will remain disabled until the user signs up for a Facebook Developer account.

[image]

Comment: My friend registered and accepted the request, but I still don't get their names when querying /me/friends , can you please tell me why? and I already added the permission user_friends

Answer (score 6):

So this is true, you can only get the "notification" on Facebook if you use a laptop or a desktop. Try having your tester visit

https://developers.facebook.com/requests/

This should work on their mobile device and provide the invitation to test

If they don't have a developer account, they will need to make one

Comment: This link no longer works. See @Azhar's answer, which links to https://developers.facebook.com/settings/developer/requests/

Answer (score 6):

Now you can accept developer and tester requests by following link

https://developers.facebook.com/settings/developer/requests/

Comment: At 2022, this is the working link.